# Trying to manipulate font size in react through state and prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to increase the font size with an onClick in react.

The sate of the font size is managed in this component; I'm also creating the method that increases the font size in this method:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NewsCard from './NewsCard'
import MenuBar from './MenuBar'
import AccordionCard from './AccordionCard'

class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      accordionFontSize: 15
    }
  }


  increaseFontSize = () => {
    this.setState({accordionFontSize: 30});
    console.log('hello2');
  }

  render() {

    const { accordionFontSize } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
          <div>
              <MenuBar increaseFontSize={this.increaseFontSize} />
          </div>
          <br/>
          <AccordionCard accordionFontSize={accordionFontSize} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainPage;
```

The component that, once clicked, increases the font size, is here:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LeagueSelect from './LeagueSelect'
import IncreaseTexSize from './TextIncrement'
import DecreaseTexSize from './DecreaseTextSize'


class MenuBar extends Component {
  render() {

    let leagueSelectStyle = {
            float: 'left',
            paddingLeft: 10,
            paddingRight: 12
          }
    let increaseTextSize = {
            float: 'left',
            paddingLeft: 5,
          }
    let decreaseTextSize = {
            float: 'left',
            paddingRight: 5
          }

    return (
      <div>
      <div style={leagueSelectStyle}><LeagueSelect /></div> <div style={increaseTextSize} onClick={this.props.increaseFontSize}><IncreaseTexSize /></div><div style={increaseTextSize}><DecreaseTexSize /></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuBar;
```

This is the third component that is actually increasing in size:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Accordion, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class AccordionCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    activeIndex: null,
    player: "Antonio Brown",
    headline: "Rapsheet: Steelers sending A.B. to the Bills",
    position: "WR",
    league: "NFL",
    team: "Steelers",
    city: "Pittsburgh",
    report:"NFL Network's Ian Rapoport reports the Steelers are closing in on a deal to trade Antonio Brown to the Bills.",
    spin: "Wow. It will be interesting to see what the Bills are sending the Steelers' direction, as Buffalo doesn't have any extra picks in the early rounds, holding their own first-, second-, and third-round picks, with the first being at No. 9 overall. Going from Ben Roethlisberger and Pittsburgh to Josh Allen and Buffalo is a significant downgrade for Brown both in football and life. His fantasy prospects will take a big hit with this deal. More to come when the deal is final.",
    source: "Ian Rapoport",
    linkSource: "https://twitter.com/RapSheet/status/1103874992914096131",
    fontSize: `${this.props.accordionFontSize}px`
  }
}

  handleClick = (e, titleProps) => {
    const { index } = titleProps
    const { activeIndex } = this.state
    const newIndex = activeIndex === index ? -1 : index

    this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex })
  }

  render() {

    let reportAndSpin = {
      float: 'left',
      textAlign: 'justify',
      paddingLeft: "2%",
      paddingRight: "2%",
    }

    let accordionStyle = {
      float: 'left',
      paddingLeft: "2%",
      fontSize: this.state.fontSize
    }

    const { activeIndex, headline, report, spin } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
      <div style={accordionStyle}><Accordion>
        <Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === 0} index={0} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Icon name='dropdown' />
          {headline}
        </Accordion.Title>
        <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === 0}>
          <p style={reportAndSpin}>
              {report}
          </p>
          <p style={reportAndSpin}>
              {spin}
          </p>
        </Accordion.Content>
      </Accordion></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I know the method is propped over correctly, because the increaseFontSize method console.logs 'hello2' once clicked. For whatever reason, it doesn't seem to be updating the font size.

Comment: Your `MenuBar` component seems to use a bunch of undefined variables.

Comment: Example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/3rwywn57q

Comment: I updated the post to include the undefined the undefined variables that a previously left out. I still don't see what's really different between what you did and what I have in place. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For one, the code you posted doesn't contain any mention of the CSS property `fontSize`. How and where are you telling the app which font size to use?

Comment: I just posted as you were writing haha. I put the last component in that is increasing in size--a third component

Comment: The constructor is only called once, when the instance is created. Therefore `this.state.fontSize` won't ever change. The state doesn't have to be involved anyway, just use `fontSize: this.props.accordionFontSize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update your state since it's dependent on your props. The constructor is called only once, hence subsequent changes to state via props will not be reflected.

```
class AccordionCard extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (state.accordionFontSize !== props.accordionFontSize) {
      return {
        fontSize: `${props.accordionFontSize}px`
      }
    }

   // Return null if the state hasn't changed
   return null;
  }
}
```

This is the whole component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Accordion, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class AccordionCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    activeIndex: null,
    player: "Antonio Brown",
    headline: "Rapsheet: Steelers sending A.B. to the Bills",
    position: "WR",
    league: "NFL",
    team: "Steelers",
    city: "Pittsburgh",
    report:"NFL Network's Ian Rapoport reports the Steelers are closing in on a deal to trade Antonio Brown to the Bills.",
    spin: "Wow. It will be interesting to see what the Bills are sending the Steelers' direction, as Buffalo doesn't have any extra picks in the early rounds, holding their own first-, second-, and third-round picks, with the first being at No. 9 overall. Going from Ben Roethlisberger and Pittsburgh to Josh Allen and Buffalo is a significant downgrade for Brown both in football and life. His fantasy prospects will take a big hit with this deal. More to come when the deal is final.",
    source: "Ian Rapoport",
    linkSource: "https://twitter.com/RapSheet/status/1103874992914096131",
    fontSize: `${this.props.accordionFontSize}px`
   }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (state.accordionFontSize !== props.accordionFontSize) {
      return {
        fontSize: `${props.accordionFontSize}px`
      }
    }
    return null
  }

  handleClick = (e, titleProps) => {
    const { index } = titleProps
    const { activeIndex } = this.state
    const newIndex = activeIndex === index ? -1 : index

    this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex })
  }

  render() {

    let reportAndSpin = {
      float: 'left',
      textAlign: 'justify',
      paddingLeft: "2%",
      paddingRight: "2%",
    }

    let accordionStyle = {
      float: 'left',
      paddingLeft: "2%",
      fontSize: this.state.fontSize
    }

    const { activeIndex, headline, report, spin } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
      <div style={accordionStyle}><Accordion>
        <Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === 0} index={0} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Icon name='dropdown' />
          {headline}
        </Accordion.Title>
        <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === 0}>
          <p style={reportAndSpin}>
              {report}
          </p>
          <p style={reportAndSpin}>
              {spin}
          </p>
        </Accordion.Content>
      </Accordion></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: The size of the AccordianCard changes when I update the size in Menu Bar, so the size is passing correctly as it currently  configured.

Comment: You then need to refactor the question. I still don't understand what your question is? What is not updating in what component?

Comment: The state of size is not updating in Main Page component when I try to update the state. The state of size in Main Page is propped to the Accordian Card component; the last component that I posted. When I manually change the size in the state of Main Page, it updates the size, so I know the information is propped correctly.

Comment: Updated the answer...check now.

Comment: While this works, making the fontSize part of the state isn't required at all. One can simply insert the prop into the style object.

Comment: Yeah that is even  better. Just provided with a solution to what you were trying to achieve.